# Add the month to the monthly Open

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon All,

I would like to put the monthly Open for each line.new (as Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May etc).

Any advice direction would be gratefully received.

I have coded the line.new to appear to the right to try and keep the chart cleaner.

Also is there a better way to pick up the monthly opens, rather than the way I have coded below.

```
//@version=4
study("Levels", shorttitle="Levels", overlay=true)

////////////////////////////////////////
ExtendAxisLine = input(false, title="Extend Monthly Opens", group="Opens", tooltip="Extend Line Across Chart")
ExtendOption = ExtendAxisLine ? extend.both : extend.right


////////////////////////////////////////
MonthlyInputColor = input(color.purple, title="Monthly", inline = "Input 0") 


///////////////////////////////////////

//Monthly Opens
m1Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m2Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m3Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[2], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m4Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[3], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m5Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[4], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m6Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[5], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m7Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[6], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m8Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[7], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m9Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[8], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m10Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[9], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m11Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[10], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
m12Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open[11], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

PriceMonthly = input(true, title="Show Monthly Opens", inline = "Input 0")

// Line Var
var line m1OpenLine = na
var line m2OpenLine = na
var line m3OpenLine = na
var line m4OpenLine = na
var line m5OpenLine = na
var line m6OpenLine = na
var line m7OpenLine = na
var line m8OpenLine = na
var line m9OpenLine = na
var line m10OpenLine = na
var line m11OpenLine = na
var line m12OpenLine = na

//Label Var
var label m1OpenLabel = na
var label m2OpenLabel = na
var label m3OpenLabel = na
var label m4OpenLabel = na
var label m5OpenLabel = na
var label m6OpenLabel = na
var label m7OpenLabel = na
var label m8OpenLabel = na
var label m9OpenLabel = na
var label m10OpenLabel = na
var label m11OpenLabel = na
var label m12OpenLabel = na


////////////////////Monthly
Spaces = "                                                                                                                                      "

if PriceMonthly 
    m1OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m1Open, bar_index, m1Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m2OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m2Open, bar_index, m2Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m3OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m3Open, bar_index, m3Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m4OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m4Open, bar_index, m4Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m5OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m5Open, bar_index, m5Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m6OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m6Open, bar_index, m6Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m7OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m7Open, bar_index, m7Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m8OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m8Open, bar_index, m8Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m9OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m9Open, bar_index, m9Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m10OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m10Open, bar_index, m10Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m11OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m11Open, bar_index, m11Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m12OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m12Open, bar_index, m12Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)

//Create Label

    m1OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m1Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m1Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m2OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m2Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m2Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m3OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m3Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m3Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m4OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m4Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m4Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m5OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m5Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m5Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m6OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m6Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m6Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m7OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m7Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m7Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m8OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m8Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m8Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m9OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m9Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m9Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m10OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m10Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m10Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m11OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m11Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m11Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m12OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m12Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+tostring(month)+tostring(m12Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)

//Delete Line
    line.delete(m1OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m2OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m3OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m4OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m5OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m6OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m7OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m8OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m9OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m10OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m11OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m12OpenLine[1])    

//Delete Label    
    label.delete(m1OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m2OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m3OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m4OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m5OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m6OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m7OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m8OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m9OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m10OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m11OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m12OpenLabel[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
//@version=4
study("Levels", shorttitle="Levels", overlay=true)

////////////////////////////////////////
ExtendAxisLine = input(false, title="Extend Monthly Opens", group="Opens", tooltip="Extend Line Across Chart")
ExtendOption = ExtendAxisLine ? extend.both : extend.right

var string[]    a_months = str.split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec",",")

////////////////////////////////////////
MonthlyInputColor = input(color.yellow, title="Monthly", inline = "Input 0") 


///////////////////////////////////////

//Monthly Opens
[m1Open,m2Open,m3Open,m4Open,m5Open,m6Open,m7Open,m8Open,m9Open,m10Open,m11Open,m12Open] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", [open,open[1],open[2],open[3],open[4],open[5],open[6],open[7],open[8],open[9],open[10],open[11]], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

//Month numbers for Opens
[month1,month2,month3,month4,month5,month6,month7,month8,month9,month10,month11,month12] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", [month,month[1],month[2],month[3],month[4],month[5],month[6],month[7],month[8],month[9],month[10],month[11]], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)


PriceMonthly = input(true, title="Show Monthly Opens", inline = "Input 0")

// Line Var
var line m1OpenLine = na
var line m2OpenLine = na
var line m3OpenLine = na
var line m4OpenLine = na
var line m5OpenLine = na
var line m6OpenLine = na
var line m7OpenLine = na
var line m8OpenLine = na
var line m9OpenLine = na
var line m10OpenLine = na
var line m11OpenLine = na
var line m12OpenLine = na

//Label Var
var label m1OpenLabel = na
var label m2OpenLabel = na
var label m3OpenLabel = na
var label m4OpenLabel = na
var label m5OpenLabel = na
var label m6OpenLabel = na
var label m7OpenLabel = na
var label m8OpenLabel = na
var label m9OpenLabel = na
var label m10OpenLabel = na
var label m11OpenLabel = na
var label m12OpenLabel = na


////////////////////Monthly
var Spaces = "                                                                                                                                      "

if PriceMonthly 
    m1OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m1Open, bar_index, m1Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m2OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m2Open, bar_index, m2Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m3OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m3Open, bar_index, m3Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m4OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m4Open, bar_index, m4Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m5OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m5Open, bar_index, m5Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m6OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m6Open, bar_index, m6Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m7OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m7Open, bar_index, m7Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m8OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m8Open, bar_index, m8Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m9OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m9Open, bar_index, m9Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m10OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m10Open, bar_index, m10Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m11OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m11Open, bar_index, m11Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)
    m12OpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], m12Open, bar_index, m12Open, color=MonthlyInputColor, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)

//Create Label
    m1OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m1Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month1 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m1Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m2OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m2Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month2 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m2Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m3OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m3Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month3 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m3Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m4OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m4Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month4 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m4Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m5OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m5Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month5 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m5Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m6OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m6Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month6 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m6Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m7OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m7Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month7 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m7Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m8OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m8Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month8 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m8Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m9OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m9Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "  + array.get(a_months, month9 - 1)   + ": " + tostring(m9Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m10OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m10Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+ array.get(a_months, month10 - 1)  + ": " + tostring(m10Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m11OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m11Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+ array.get(a_months, month11 - 1)  + ": " + tostring(m11Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    m12OpenLabel := label.new(bar_index, m12Open, text = Spaces+"mOpen - "+ array.get(a_months, month12 - 1)  + ": " + tostring(m12Open), color=MonthlyInputColor, textcolor=MonthlyInputColor, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)

//Delete Line
    line.delete(m1OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m2OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m3OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m4OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m5OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m6OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m7OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m8OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m9OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m10OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m11OpenLine[1])    
    line.delete(m12OpenLine[1])    

//Delete Label    
    label.delete(m1OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m2OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m3OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m4OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m5OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m6OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m7OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m8OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m9OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m10OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m11OpenLabel[1])    
    label.delete(m12OpenLabel[1])
```

Which yields

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you Bjorn as always.